# Converter uint16_t para int

Tags: c, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo, int

Estou fazendo um projeto em que um detector de distância armazena a distancia em uma variável `uint16_t`, e eu preciso transformá-la em `int` para fazer as comparações, mas não encontro em lugar nenhum como fazer isso. Como fazer?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Um cabe no outro perfeitamente e uma promoção é feita automaticamente. Olha que simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
 
int main(void) {
    uint16_t x = 1000;
    int y = x;
    printf("%d", y);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/G32LaN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/shqxeqlp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Uint16Toint.c)